# Normalizing a list of items in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, unique, distinct, normalize

I am trying to get a list of all unit test assemblies under the root of my project. I can do this as follows:

```
<CreateItem Include="**\bin\**\*.UnitTest.*.dll">
   <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Items"/>
</CreateItem>
```

However, this will find the same DLLs multiple times since they exist in multiple sub-directories. Is there an easy way for me to normalize based on item metadata (ie. the file name and extension) so that I get a list of unique unit test DLLs? Or do I have to resort to writing my own task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MSBuild Extension Pack](https://github.com/mikefourie/MSBuildExtensionPack) contains the task *MSBuildHelper*, supporting the command *RemoveDuplicateFiles*.

```
<CreateItem Include="**\bin\**\*.UnitTest.*.dll">
    <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Items"/>
</CreateItem>
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper TaskAction="RemoveDuplicateFiles" InputItems1="@(Items)">
    <Output TaskParameter="OutputItems" ItemName="Items"/>
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper>
```

Answer (score 9):

Even though this is old, I could never get Thomas solution to work myself, but I did find sort of a workaround using only built-in commands with v4.0 of msbuild:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TestAssemblies Include="$(SolutionRoot)\**\bin\*.Tests.dll" />
    <TestItems Include="%(TestAssemblies.FileName)%(TestAssemblies.Extension)">
        <ItemPath>%(TestAssemblies.Identity)</ItemPath>
    </TestItems>
    <DistinctTestItems Include="@(TestItems->Distinct())"></DistinctTestItems>
</ItemGroup>
<Message Text="%(DistinctTestItems.ItemPath)" Importance="high" />
```

Documentation: [Item Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886422.aspx)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The built-in functionality is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I had a good search online and couldn't find any way of doing this. If anyone knows a clean built-in way then please let me know. In the meantime, I wrote a simple task to do the job. The usage looks like this:

```
<NormalizeByMetadata Items="@(ItemsToNormalize)" MetadataName="Filename">
    <Output TaskParameter="NormalizedItems" ItemName="MyNormalizedItems"/>
</NormalizeByMetadata>
```

After the above task has executed, `MyNormalizedItems` will contain only those items from `ItemsToNormalize` that have a unique value for the `Filename` metadata. If two or more items have the same value for their `Filename` metadata, the first match will be included in the output.

The code for the MSBuild task is:

```
public class NormalizeByMetadata : Task
{
    [Required]
    public ITaskItem[] Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required]
    public string MetadataName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Output]
    public ITaskItem[] NormalizedItems
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        NormalizedItems = Items.Distinct(new ItemEqualityComparer(MetadataName)).ToArray();
        return true;
    }

    private sealed class ItemEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ITaskItem>
    {
        private readonly string _metadataName;

        public ItemEqualityComparer(string metadataName)
        {
            Debug.Assert(metadataName != null);
            _metadataName = metadataName;
        }

        public bool Equals(ITaskItem x, ITaskItem y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                return x == y;
            }

            var xMetadata = x.GetMetadata(_metadataName);
            var yMetadata = y.GetMetadata(_metadataName);
            return string.Equals(xMetadata, yMetadata);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ITaskItem obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            var objMetadata = obj.GetMetadata(_metadataName);
            return objMetadata.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How create unit test for NormalizeByMetadata Task ?